# Baseline deviation graph in Oracle APEX5.0

Tags: oracle-apex

In Oracle APEX 5.0 , I want to create a baseline deviation graph  where in it should display the graph in below format.
[image]

Given X axis  is the date column and Y axis is  the column with numeric value , I should be able to highlight the least value through a line ( as you can see in above graph the line marked in red is a baseline value ) in addition to the linear display on chart.So far I tried using "D3 Line chart" plugin but seems its not displaying the chart in expected format.

Could you please suggest if its possible to create such a chart? What plugin is required for that?

Answer (score 0):

i think you dont need a plugin

you can achieve this need by using a chart sample with multiple series
and you can give your secondary serie with a fixed baseline value like

SELECT link, label, series_1_value [, series_2_value [, ...]]
FROM   ...

SELECT link, label, series_1_value , 2
FROM   ...

Comment: I can use multiple series  but I need to display the graph for same set of records.This is my sql query select null link,time_stamp LABEL , login_value "loginval" from user_history where user_id='cx123';     I want to draw a baseline for least value of "login_value" column which is a number datatype . How do I use multiple series here?

Comment: i think addin /  x as "baselineValue"  /should be enough  like select null link,time_stamp LABEL , login_value "loginval", 3 as "baselineValue"  from user_history where user_id='cx123';